# Is this PRG secure?

Tags: cryptanalysis, pseudo-random-generator, distinguisher

$G$ is a secure PRG in range $\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}^{n+1}$.

Let us define $G'(S)=G(S\oplus G(S)_{1,...,n})$, s.t. $G(S)_{1,...,n}$ is the first n bits of $G(S)$.

Is $G'(S)$ a secure PRG?

### Intuition

I'd like to say that since $G(S)$ is a secure PRG then it's first n bits should also be pseudo random, else if they weren't, we'd have a distinguisher for the first n-bits, and then last bit could be 0 or 1, and we could distinguish $G(S)$ with high probability... but I might be missing something.

Comment: Is this homework? You should explicitly say so. Anyway, your intuition is taking you in the wrong direction.

Comment: @YehudaLindell This is homework without grade, it's an extra. Actually I study in your university but this is not your course. (;

Comment: Hint: it is NOT secure.

Comment: It seems $G'$ is not expanding. So it's not even an insecure PRG.